# Jarlauncher was not found when using spring boot layertools mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, executable-jar

I extracted my app build file using `layertools` jar mode.
(ref. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#container-images.dockerfiles)

As a result, four files were extracted as follows.

```
application
dependencies
snapshot-dependencies
spring-boot-loader
```

Then, in the same directory, I tried to run the application by executing the following command:

```
$java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

However, an error occurred.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

`MANIFEST.MF` is as follows.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.henry.myproject.HelloApplicationKt
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.6.4
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
```

**Why does this error occur?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the four directories is intended to be used as a separate layer in a Docker image. They need to be copied into a single directory. In a Dockerfile, that would look like this:

```
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
```

The application can then be launched from the directory into which the layers have been copied.

Comment: I want to run it on the localhost machine before applying it to the docker. The four directories(dependencise, spring-boot-loader ..) are already in the same directory. The problem is that jar launcher cannot be found and executed.

Comment: The four directories are four separate directories. The contents of the four directories need to be combined into a single directory. That's what the copy commands above are doing when building the Docker image. If you want to run it on the local machine, you'll have to do the same there too.

Comment: I didn't combine the contents of four directories into one directory. When combined into one directory, it works normally. Thanks for your help !